# Powershell Asynchronous Function Call

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

I'm trying to create some sort of Service Script that notifies me when a specific computer in the network is online. To achieve this, I'd like to have a function that runs in the background and checks every x seconds whether the computer is reachable (through an ICMP package) or not.

Pseudo code:

```
class Computer{
[bool]$IsOnline
[ScriptBlock]$InvokeFunction = {
    Notify()
}
}

$collectionOfComputers = @()

function Invoke-Worker{
    while($true){
        foreach($computer in $collectionOfComputers){
            ping $computer
            if($computer.IsOnline){
                $computer.InvokeFunction()
            }
        }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
}
```

I hope what I'm trying to do is achievable with powershell and the question is okay to be asked.

Comment: Have you tried? Nothing you've described is far out of reach with PowerShell

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, I've tried but when I run the Invoke-Worker with a Start-Job, it has no access to the variable $collectionOfComputers, neither does the Notify() function work / give any output.

Comment: During each poll, do you want to know what computers in the list are online, which new ones have come online during each poll, or which ones have changed state since the last poll (online and offline)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic structure but I think meets all of the requirements you mentioned and some you don't:

```
$Status = @{}

while ($true) 
{
    ## By continually retrieving the contents of the file, will allow you to update the input on the fly and have the script dynamically adjust
    $Computers = Get-Content 'computers.txt'

    if ($Computers.Count -gt 0) 
    {

        foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
        {

            if (-not($Status[$Computer])) 
            {
                $Status[$Computer] = [pscustomobject]@{
                    Name = $Computer
                    IsOnline = $false
                    StateChange = $null
                }
            }

            ## If IsOnline NOW
            if (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet) 
            {
                ## If IsOnline NOW compared to the state on the last poll
                if ($Status[$Computer].IsOnline)
                {
                    $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $false
                }
                else 
                {
                    $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $true
                }

                ## Set the new online state for our object
                $Status[$Computer].IsOnline = $true
            }
            else 
            {
                ## If IsOnline NOW compared to the state on the last poll
                if ($Status[$Computer].IsOnline) 
                {
                    $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $true
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $false
                }

                ## Set the new online state for our object
                $Status[$Computer].IsOnline = $false
            }
        }
    }

    $Status

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```

Variant:  Producer/Consumer Parallelism -- without the Producer (still have to poll the output object to retrieve the results, even though the icmp polling is happening in a different runspace)

```
## Adapted from Lee Holmes Producer/Consumer Parallelism here:  https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2018/09/05/producer-consumer-parallelism-in-powershell/
$parallelScript = {
    param(

        ## The output buffer to write responses to
        $OutputQueue,

        ## State tracking, to help threads communicate
        ## how much progress they've made
        $ThreadId, $ShouldExit
    )

    ## Continually work until
    ## the 'ShouldExit' flag is set

    $Status = @{}
    $workItem = $null
    while(! $ShouldExit.Value)
    {
        ## By continually retrieving the contents of the file, will allow you to update the input on the fly and have the script dynamically adjust
        $Computers = Get-Content 'C:\users\user\Desktop\computers.txt'

        if ($Computers.Count -gt 0) 
        {

            foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
            {

                if (-not($Status[$Computer])) 
                {
                    $Status[$Computer] = [pscustomobject]@{
                        Name = $Computer
                        IsOnline = $false
                        StateChange = $null
                    }
                }

                ## If IsOnline NOW
                if (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet) 
                {
                    ## If IsOnline NOW compared to the state on the last poll
                    if ($Status[$Computer].IsOnline)
                    {
                        $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $false
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $true
                    }

                    ## Set the new online state for our object
                    $Status[$Computer].IsOnline = $true
                }
                else 
                {
                    ## If IsOnline NOW compared to the state on the last poll
                    if ($Status[$Computer].IsOnline) 
                    {
                        $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $true
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $Status[$Computer].StateChange = $false
                    }

                    ## Set the new online state for our object
                    $Status[$Computer].IsOnline = $false
                }
            }
        }

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

        ## Add the result to the output queue
        $OutputQueue.Enqueue($Status)
    }
    else
    {
        ## If there was no work, wait a bit for more.
        Start-Sleep -m 100
    }
}

## Create a set of background PowerShell instances to do work, based on the
## number of available processors.
$threads = 1
$runspaces = 1..$threads | Foreach-Object { [PowerShell]::Create() }
$outputProgress = New-Object 'Int[]' $threads
$outputQueue = New-Object 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[Object]'
$shouldExit = $false

## Spin up each of our PowerShell runspaces. Once invoked, these are actively
## waiting for work and consuming once available.
for($counter = 0; $counter -lt $threads; $counter++)
{  
    $null = $runspaces[$counter].AddScript($parallelScript).
        AddParameter("OutputQueue", $outputQueue).
        AddParameter("ThreadId", $counter).
        AddParameter("ShouldExit", [ref] $shouldExit).BeginInvoke()
}


## Wait for our worker threads to complete processing the
## work.
try
{
    do
    {

        ## If there were any results, output them.
        $scriptOutput = $null
        while($outputQueue.TryDequeue([ref] $scriptOutput))
        {
            $scriptOutput
        }     

        Start-Sleep -m 100

        ## See if we still have any busy runspaces. If not, exit the loop.
        $busyRunspaces = $runspaces | Where-Object { $_.InvocationStateInfo.State -ne 'Complete' }
    } while($busyRunspaces)
}
finally
{
    ## Clean up our PowerShell instances
    foreach($runspace in $runspaces)
    {
        $runspace.Stop()
        $runspace.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to answer your comment :-) - That looks like it might work - Something I haven't mentioned before: The while($true) loop should run in a separate thread / a Job Instance. Additionally, I think you forgot to write back the new Status to the file (or am I missing something?). I'd like to use ballon tips to notify the user if a computer comes online - is this possible? The test I did (call the Show() method inside the job-instance) unfortunately did not work (I assume because it's not the main thread).

Comment: You didn't mention any of those particulars in your ask.  Signaling in and out of different threads is more difficult but certainly not impossible.  And no, it doesn't write anything to a file and there's no indication it needed .  All of the updated information is always maintained in $Status.  Where do you want this data; in memory to perform new work on or in a file?  And if so, what file?

Comment: You need to describe better the particulars of the project.  I can thread out this work with parallelism but need to know how you want to consume the updates... written to the screen, logged to a file, send via a socket address, etc. and everything in between.  If you want them written to the screen, even though the worker thread will be running infinitely to continually ping the hosts, you'll have to loop infinitely to pull the output queue object to consume the results...

Comment: I agree with you, I'm not the best when it comes to describing what I want to achieve. The Producer/Consumer parallelism seems like what I wanted. In short: I want a script that controls a worker thread. The worker thread must check a list of computers. If a computer is online, a notification (e.g. a balloon tip) should be fired. The control thread must be able to start/stop the worker, save and load a list of computers and adding and removing items to the list. I'll have a look at your solution, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the collection of computers to invoke-worker. When you pass the variable to a function you will get a copy of $collectionOfComputers then you can use start-job.

```
function Invoke-Worker($collectionOfComputers){
    while($true){
        foreach($computer in $collectionOfComputers){
            ping $computer
            if($computer.IsOnline){
                $computer.InvokeFunction()
            }
        }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
}
```

The class Computer must be part of the job.

Comment: But if I pass the collection into the function - am I able to add/remove computer objects without breaking the function while the worker works?

Comment: You should only add what you want to work on.   Once the function starts do not change the collect in it.  It would be impossible to debug it if the collection is changing during runtime.   This what think you are asking for. "I want to create Job with the function Invoke-Worker in it.  I also want to keep the current job and give it different collections of computers from my script.  I also need the output of the Job to go back to my script."  I do not know how to answer that, but it is possible. If that is what you want then update your question or make a new question.